# Microsoft Access Database Engine Invalid argument while enabling oledb connection

Tags: c#, excel

i am trying to replace a values in excel which is already available in my solution,by using oledb, it works well in local , but it threw a exception in server, i have tried all the compatibility issues, but its getting fixed.

my oledb provider is

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0,
```

Extended Properites:Extended Properties=Excel 12.0

Exception:

EventSource: Microsoft Access Database Engine
Message: Invalid argument.

Stack Trace: at

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() at
>   TTI.TaxExcise.Web.UI.Controllers.TaxableVehicleController.Exporttaxablesuspendedvehicle(Int64
>   id, String taxable)

My code here

```
if (taxablevehicle == true)
{               
    OleDbConnection DupConn = new OleDbConnection();        
     string dupConnection = Constants.Provider2007 + Constants.DataSource +
         sDupFileName + ";" + Constants.ExtendedProperties2007;
     DupConn.ConnectionString = dupConnection;
     DupConn.Open();

     //To Insert the Records                
     svlSQL = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (VIN, GrossWeight, IsLoggingVehicle, UnitNumber) Values " +
         "('" + currVehicleDataUI.VIN + "', '" + sGrossWeight + "', '" + sIsLoggingVehicle + "','" + currVehicleDataUI.UnitNumber + "')";

    if (DupConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        DupConn.Open();
    }

    OleDbCommand Comm = new OleDbCommand(svlSQL, DupConn);
    Comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Comm = null;
}
```

Comment: have you got any solution for that? I am facing exactly same issue.